# How many bases does a compound word have?

Tags: morphology, roots

How many bases does the word `girlfriends` have?

Let's take this word apart.

- `girl` -- root
- `friend` -- root
- `s` -- affix that denotes plural form

**Base** may be identical with the word root but can also be augmented with affixes while roots can not. Bases typically express a narrower lexical meaning that a root (ex: `[[forest]er]`).

So how many bases does the word `girlfriends` have?

- `girl` -- base?
- `friend` -- base?
- `girlfriend` -- base?

Comment: I think linguistics uses the term *head* where you use *base*.

Comment: As far as I remember, *head* determines the semantic category of the compound word and considered to be the rightmost stem `girl[friend]`, here `friend` is the head. I think `stem` is a more correct substitution here.

Comment: Odd. To my knowledge *stem* is only used for the unchanging part of an inflected word to which affixes are attached to obtain the inflected forms.

Comment: well let's then say stem + affix is a base. Head is not a base according to wikipedia.

Comment: "Base" is sometimes used in contrast to "stem", to refer to one of several forms of a root to which an affix may be added to form a stem.  I think I have seen that use in Indo-European studies to distinguish the various ablaut forms of a root.  And that is how Stanley Newman uses the term in his famous study of Yokuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have answered your own question.  One base, "girlfriend", since that is what the affix "s" is added to, at least judging from the meaning.  Morphologically, I guess it is not entirely obvious that "s" is not affixed to "friend", since we have the compound "musk oxen" rather than "muskoxes", where the form of the affix is determined by the second part of the compound.

Comment: What about *hangers-on*?

Comment: And *passersby*.

Comment: Base (or stem) may include only derivational affixes. So, I think *hanger-on* is a base of *hangers-on*, *passerby* is the base of *passersby*.

Comment: I believe you're confusing *base*, which might not even be a technical term in linguistics? And *head*, which definitely is a linguistics term.

Answer (score 4):

By definition, compounds have more than one base: *mice-killer* is formed from MOUSE and KILL. Unlike Noun-Verb+er compounds, most of them are opaque and the relation between the two vary. There is a long tradition giving names to these different cases. For example, one of the oldest:

- tatpurusa => *blackboard*: 1 head = BOARD, 1 modifier = BLACK
- dvandva => *bittersweet*: 2 heads = BITTER & SWEET
- bahuvrihi => *chatterbox* : no head (as a *chatterbox* is neither *chatter* nor a *box*)

A base is a lexeme used in a derivation usually for both the semantic and the phonological part of the construction. In *girlfriend* both the lexemes GIRL and FRIEND are used to build the derived word.